# Concat function not working or bad if then statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, events, concatenation

I'm making a calculator and ran into some issues with an if/else function giving me unexpected results.  The logic seems kind of sound when I run it over so I would like some input on what I may have wrong here. The code is giving unexpected results from `expressionMaker` where it seems to clear the first "if --> if " statements but none of the else ones.

Edit: thanks for the feedback. I've narrowed the issue down to this portion.

```
else if ((EventTarget == numbers) && (expression.a > 0) && (expression.operand !== 0)) {
    if (expression.b == 0) {
      expression.b = keyValue
    }
    else {
      expression.b = concat(expression.b, keyValue)
    }
    }
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("calculatorGrid");
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const miniscreen = document.getElementById("miniScreen")
const equals = document.getElementById("evaluate")
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".Nbuttons");
const clear = document.getElementById("clear");
const add = document.getElementById("plus");
const sub = document.getElementById("subtract");
const multi = document.getElementById("multiply");
const divi = document.getElementById("divide");
const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators");
let nums = document.getElementById("nums")
numbers.values  = nums.textContent
const calculate = (() => {
  const add = (a, b) => a + b;
  const sub = (a, b) => a - b;
  const mul = (a, b) => a * b;
  const div = (a, b) => a / b;
  return {
    add,
    sub,
    mul,
    div,
  };
});
const expression = {
  a: 0,
  operand: 0,
  b: 0,
};
function expressionMaker(keyValue) {
  const concat = (a, b) => {
    return ("" + a + b)
  };
  if (EventTarget == numbers && expression.a == 0 || expression.operand == 0) {
    if (expression.a == 0) {
       expression.a = keyValue
    }
    else if (expression.a > 0) {
      expression.a = concat(expression.a, keyValue)
    }
    display.innerHTML = expression.a
  }
  else if ((EventTarget == numbers) && (expression.a > 0) && (expression.operand !== 0)) {
    if (expression.b == 0) {
      expression.b = keyValue
    }
    else {
      expression.b = concat(expression.b, keyValue)
    }
    }
  else {
    null
  }
}
function evaluate() {
  var result 
  if (expression.operand == "+") {
    var result = calculate.add(expression.a, expression.b)
  }
  else if (expression.operand == "-") {
    result = calculate.sub(expression.a, expression.b)
  }
  else if (expression.operand == "x") {
    result = calculate.mul(expression.a, expression.b)
  }
  else if (expression.operand == "/") {
    result = calculate.div(expression.a,  expression.b)
  }
  else {
    return null
  }
  display.innerHTML = result
  return result
}

clear.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearOut()
})
equals.addEventListener("click", () => {
  evaluate(expression.a, expression.b)
})

function setNums() {
  let nums = document.getElementById("nums")
  numbers.values  = nums.textContent
};
setNums();
function clearOut() {
   display.textContent = 0
   expression.a = 0
   expression.operand = 0
   expression.b = 0

};



clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearOut();
});

add.addEventListener("click", () => {
  expression.operand = "+"
  display.innerHTML = "+"
})
sub.addEventListener("click", () => {
  expression.operand = "-"
  display.innerHTML = "-"
}) 
multi.addEventListener("click", () => {
  expression.operand = "x"
  display.innerHTML = "x"
})
divi.addEventListener("click", () => {
  expression.operand = "/"
  display.innerHTML = "/"
})
numbers.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var key = event.target
        let keyValue = key.textContent
        expressionMaker(keyValue)
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="display">
    <div id="miniScreen"></div>
</div>
<div id="calculatorGrid">
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="1">1</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="2">2</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="3">3</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="4">4</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="5">5</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="6">6</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="7">7</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="8">8</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="9">9</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" id="nums" data-number="0">0</button>
    <button class="operators" id="plus" data-operator="+">+</button>
    <button class="operators" id="subtract" data-operator="-">-</button>
    <button class="operators" id="multiply" data-operator="*">x</button>
    <button class="operators" id="divide" data-operator="/">÷</button>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
    <button id="evaluate"> =</button>
</div>
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by unexpected results? What results are you expecting, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting so I can't answer well, but psychic debugging: with expressions like `!expression.b == 0`, do you mean say `if expression.b is not equal to 0`? If so, you should write that as `expression.b !== 0`. `!expression.b` will be true when `b` is falsy, which probably isn't what you want, is it? You're then comparing booleans to numbers using `==` which is probably confusing things.

Comment: Sorry the unexpected behavior seems to be the function logic stopping after the first leg of the if/then statement.  After the expression.a is changed the function fails to concact or do the operand and expression.b portions. Thank you for the update on the ! ==  syntax, however changing it hasnt produced the desired results.

Comment: Ok the logical not portions are the culprit. I've reduced the use of them on the original function and got the expression.a portion to work, however the function needs to verify expression.a is NOT 0 to run the expression.b if/else statements.  !== 0 isn't getting the desired results unfortunately. I'm wondering if I'm missing something. The code in the OP has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the beginning, you can replace this function, with 4 separate "addEventListener", it's going to be way less confusing and less error prone.

```
operators.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (EventTarget == add) {
      expression.operand = "+"
      display.innerHTML = "+"
    }
    else if (EventTarget == sub) {
      expression.operand = "-"
      display.innerHTML = "-"
    }
    else if (EventTarget == multi) {
      expression.operand = "x"
      display.innerHTML = "x"
    }
    else if (EventTarget == divi) {
      expression.operand = "/"
      display.innerHTML = "/"
    }
  })
})
```

New version:

```
add.addEventListener("click", function() {
    expression.operand = "+";
    display.innerHTML += "+";
});

sub.addEventListener("click", function() {
    expression.operand = "-";
    display.innerHTML += "-";
});

multi.addEventListener("click", function() {
    expression.operand = "x";
    display.innerHTML += "x";
});

divi.addEventListener("click", function() {
    expression.operand = "/";
    display.innerHTML += "/";
});
```

---

The thing with the "unexpected behavior" is that I'm not sure what your logic was trying to do, the only thing I can suggest you is take a look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/ you'll debug a lot while coding, so it's always great to give it a try.

Using the developer tools, you'll be able to see the values in every variable at each step, that should make it easier for you to find where things are going south.

Comment: Thanks for the tip friend! I've been running tests and got the function to run as far as the "expression.b" portions, the issue now is the logical not functions not working. Adding the event listeners  this way has helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below answer is suitable for you.

**may be your elements have duplicate id like id="nums"**

you can also complete like this..

```js
const miniscreen = document.getElementById("miniScreen");


function clearValue(){
  miniscreen.innerHTML=0;
}

function mini(param){
  if(miniscreen.innerHTML==0){
    miniscreen.innerHTML=param;
  }else{
  miniscreen.innerHTML+=param;
  }
}

function calculate(){
  
  miniscreen.innerHTML=eval(miniscreen.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="display">
    <div id="miniScreen">0</div>
</div>
<div id="calculatorGrid">
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('1')" data-number="1">1</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('2')"  data-number="2">2</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('3')"  data-number="3">3</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('4')">4</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('5')">5</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('6')">6</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('7')">7</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('8')">8</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('9')">9</button>
    <button class="Nbuttons" onclick="mini('0')">0</button>
    <button class="operators" id="plus" onclick="mini('+')">+</button>
    <button class="operators" id="subtract" onclick="mini('-')">-</button>
    <button class="operators" id="multiply" onclick="mini('*')">x</button>
    <button class="operators" id="divide" onclick="mini('/')">÷</button>
    <button id="clear" onclick="clearValue()">clear</button>
    <button id="evaluate" onclick="calculate()"> =</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Thank you.